# Is rooting the Samsung Galaxy S5 G900V impossible?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, rooting, samsung-galaxy-s-5, bootloader-lock, verizon

I've been trying to root my Verizon S5 (SM G900V) for a while now, but to no avail. It has Android 5.0 lollipop on it right now. I was able to easily root my S4, but nothing seems to work for the S5. I've tried towelroot (which says "device not supported" no matter what modstrings I use), various rooting methods directly from my computer (such as Kingo), CF auto root, flashing other roms (almost bricked my phone because the bootloader is locked), and several other methods, all which have failed. I've been searching all over the internet for a way to root the G900V, but everything I found has failed, and some people are saying that Verizon has updated their phones and fixed the vulnerabilities so that they are unrootable. Is there any possible way I can root my phone, or install a custom rom that is rooted like Cyanogenmod? I'm aware that my phone has a locked bootloader, and I don't know how to unlock it on the G900V. Or, will I just have to wait until someone finds a way years later or I get a new phone?

Comment: Have you checked [this project here on xda](http://forum.xda-developers.com/verizon-galaxy-s5/development/note-5-port-norma-v3-2-final-fast-t3369813)? This thread states instructions for installing the rom for locked bootloaders

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you cannot root your phone the normal way, because Verizon won't let you unlock your bootloader. I believe [Kingroot](https://kingroot.net) should work. It was able to successfully root my Samsung Galaxy S3 running 4.4.4. If that doesn't work I would try [King**o**root](http://kingoapp.com). Hope this helps. We all hate Verizon for keeping our bootloaders locked.

If those don't work, I would suggest finding a Carrier unlocked phone. When you go to Verizon to get it hooked up, make sure familybase is disabled, or they won't be able to hook it up. I recently was able to hook up an unlocked Nexus 6p (great phone).

Good luck!